# Apache Camel, multicast and loop

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm using Apache Camel for routing Rest request.
I want to get some `count` of messages from queue. But i have troubles with it.
I'm trying following code:

```
from("direct:read_some_messages")
    .multicast(new GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy(), false)
      .loop(count)
        .pollEnrich().simple(AMQ_PATH_TEMPLATE).timeout(receiveTimeout).end()
      .end()
    .end()
    .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
    .end();
```

But in sush way `multicast` add only 1 result of `pollEnrich`.
Can anyone help me with it? Or may it can be solved another way without `multicast`?

p.s. i'm new in camel

Comment: In this situation you only have a single Exchange moving through that route. That's why you only get a single pollEnrich invocation.

Comment: I think you should try and read through the Camel documentation on [Enterprise Integration Patterns](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/eips/enterprise-integration-patterns.html) to try and find the correct pieces to get to the end result of what you need.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more as in what are you trying to achieve? Or may be explain what are you trying to do in the defined route?

Comment: @CyberMafia Im trying to agregate several messages from queue in one result exchange. The result body should be List<Map> and converted to json. In queue i have Map message.

Comment: Ok so basically you want to aggregate multiple exchanges into one. You are looking at Aggregate EIP pattern. Check this page: 
https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/eips/aggregate-eip.html#_aggregating

Specifically check the second example of this section. That custom aggregation strategy combines multiple exchanges into one arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

I get needed result sush way:

```
  from("direct:read_some_messages")
    .loopDoWhile(simple("${header[loop_counter]} > 0"))
      .pollEnrich().simple(AMQ_PATH_TEMPLATE).timeout(receiveTimeout)
      .aggregationStrategy(new ArrayListAggregationStrategy()).id("pollEnrich_from_activeMQ_with_page_id")
      .end()
    .end()
    .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
    .end();
```

In `ArrayListAggregationStrategy` i'm decreasing `loop_counter` and adding some logic to stop loop beforehand if need.